# How to determine if kafka is running encryption in transit?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there some specific place, setting or script that will tell me if kafka is running encryption in transit?

The current kafka cluster is running on version 0.11.0.0(yes old! very aware)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the brokers, then their settings have `SSL://` in the `listeners` which will indicate its using TLS over the wire

Otherwise, the client code might be required to define various SSL settings

Even if using plaintext listeners, there's nothing preventing a client library from implementing message encryption itself in other ways